# Performace issues when using spring ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, performance

I m using Spring to create forms and display them in a layout area automatically when user clicks on a menu:

```
ApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("package");
AbstractComponent form = (AbstractComponent)ac.getBean(formName);       
layout.addComponent( form );
```

All is working fine, the issues is that, there are several hundreds forms, so when user clicks on a menu, it last almost 8 seconds to load the form. The things is that, if I understand well,  the  bean container instantied all the forms?

Is there any way to increase performace, I m using correctly the `ApplicationContext`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would pre-loading context before user does any clicks work? Then on user click application will have to only **find** a form in already instantiated context not to **instantiate** the whole context.

Comment: Thanks dopamint, yes, I applied a Singleton pattern and it resolver the performance problem. See my answer for futher info

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the issue was due to a newbie error. When the user clicked the form the method responsible for creating the ApplicationContext created a new ApplicationContext everytime. So applying the Singleton pattern resolved the problem:

public class FormLoader{
        static ApplicationContext ac = null;

```
    public FormLoader() {
        if( ac == null ) {
            ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("package");
        }
    }

    public void loadForm( ... ) {
        AbstractComponent form = (AbstractComponent)ac.getBean(nombreForm);
        layout.addComponent( form );

    }
}
```